# Someone is bothering me by messaging through websites message services

Tags: network, sms

Someone is sending me sms from last few weeks through 'SMS sending websites' who don't publish the sender name in the message. Sometimes it shows ' sent through websms' in the message. Please help if their is any way to know who is that person? And if it is not possible to know, is their anyway to stop these unwanted sms?

Comment: Not really. You might want to contact your phone network to report the problem though. If the situation gets very bad they will issue you a new number.

Comment: "*is [there] any way to know who is that person?*" - no. "*is there any way to stop these unwanted sms?*" - no.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to tell who it was sent from, at least without police involvement (such as a warrant to the SMS website). Even if you got this far, the most that the website would give the police is an IP address, and it would be even more difficult for them to tie this to a specific person. So realistically, unless these messages are threatening someone, there is no way to tell who these SMS messages were sent from.

As for blocking these SMS messages, you will likely need to approach it in 2 ways. If you get messages repeatedly from the same number, you can block messages from that number with either your phone or service provider. If the phone number changes each time but you know what service they're coming from, sometimes the service allows you to enter your phone number into a "do not contact" list. Otherwise, there's not much you can do to block these messages. You could change phone numbers or maybe set your phone to block text messages from numbers that are not in your contact list.